# How do I connect to MongoDB v2.6.12 from Django 1.10 (python3.4) and pymongo v3.4?

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine, django-1.10

I am new to Django, and I set up a mysites app using the tutorial [given here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/)

I followed [this guide](https://sandeepkumarrai.wordpress.com/) to setup mongodb with Django using mongoengine

However, I keep getting the following error everytime I try running the server:

```
(myVirtEnv_1) [root@sandbox1 django-mongoadmin]# python mysite/manage.py runserver 99
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 124, in get_connection
    _connections[alias] = connection if connection else connection_class(**conn_settings)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 422, in __init__
    for k, v in keyword_opts.items())
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 422, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in keyword_opts.items())
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 539, in validate
    value = validator(option, value)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 301, in validate_read_preference
    raise TypeError("%r is not a read preference." % (value,))
TypeError: False is not a read preference.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysite/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/blrasp/django-mongoadmin/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 137, in <module>
    connect(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, host=MONGO_HOST, port=MONGO_PORT)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 164, in connect
    return get_connection(alias)
  File "/root/blrasp/myVirtEnv_1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 126, in get_connection
    raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
False is not a read preference.
```

Here is my settings.py file:

```
(myVirtEnv_1) [root@sandbox1 django-mongoadmin]# cat mysite/mysite/settings.py 
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(m!6up^g!2k=7xu5se_jnr9q7=1uyko6sjf%re)yh%tpx1(a8+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mongoadmin',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
           'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
 )
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'

from mongoengine import connect
MONGO_DATABASE_NAME = 'test'
MONGO_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
connect(MONGO_DATABASE_NAME, host=MONGO_HOST, port=MONGO_PORT)
```

I have alread checked the following:

- MongoDB is Definitely up and running
- I checked whether the mongoDB server is accessible by changing the MONGO_HOST value from '127.0.0.1' to '0.0.0.0'. Same error.

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Environment:

- OS: RHEL 7.3
- Python: 3.4
- Django: 1.10
- MongoDB: 2.6.12
- PyMongo: 3.4
- MongoEngine: 0.11.0

Comment: do you get the same error when you change MONGO_HOST to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @Danlee, Thank you for the help 

Yes, I just tried this and checked. I got the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be having the issue listed here: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/935
Try downgrading Pymongo to 2.8.

Also look here: [Django DB Connection with mangoDB using mangoengine gives me error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593589/django-db-connection-with-mangodb-using-mangoengine-gives-me-error)

Comment: Thank you !! 
Downgrading worked for me. 
On a similar note, do you know whether progress is being done to improve MongoDB integration with Django?

Any info would be helpful]